# test case format for login page contains 2 fields only

Tags: asp.net

What is the format of writing the test case documentation for login page which contains only userid and password field and for birth form?

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the Username as string in the User name field, which is of maximum .
2. Provide the relevant Password, after giving the password if click on submit button and if the password and username matches for a particular user then the application allows the user to login or else gives an error message.